# unable to ping/send http requests to RHEL tomcat server on Azure

Tags: http, azure, rhel

Note - I am fully aware that there are lot of similar issues posted before, but I tried NSG settings, psping but nothing seem to work

All, I brought up a RHEL7.3 server on Azure and installed JDK1.8 and Tomcat8. After starting Tomcat, I tried an http request from my browser:

http://XX.yy.zz.abc:8080/ but I was unable to get the index page

I also created an inbound security rule to allow HTTP and also allow IP range from our company.

Even worse is, when I tried pinging to this IP from my desktop computer, I am unable to ping the same - it is timing out.

Please note that in the past, I've been able to bring up servers and be able to connect from desktops without any issues - in a similar azure-companynetwork setup.

Am I missing anything here?

Comment: ICMP isn't supported from external sources (stated in numerous questions/answers about this exact topic), so you'll never get a ping response.

Comment: Could you access your web by using `127.0.0.1:8080`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so pings do not work, you shouldn't even try that. What you should check is the firewall on you RHEL VM and check you've allowed port 8080 on you NSG, also your VM should have a PublicIP attached

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, the NSG is setup to allow my specific address and also allow http requests (8080). I was able to login into the VM and startup tomcat from my local computer using the public IP

Comment: then you need to check the firewall

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you had better check as the following ways:

1.Please ensure you could access your web by using `127.0.0.1:8080` on your VM.

2.Check your service listening.

```
netstat -ant|grep 8080
```

Please ensure 8080 is listening on `tcp` not `tcp6`.

3.Open firewall port on RHEL.

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent
```

More information about RHEL firewall please refer to this [link](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Security_Guide/sec-Using_Firewalls.html).

4.Open port on Azure NSG.

NSG could be associated with NIC and subnet, you should check all of them.

Answer (score 0):

All,

It looks like there is an input firewall inside of RHEL7.3 that is preventing connections.  I just stopped it using 
    service firewalld stop

I am able to get the home page.

Comment: No, I suggest you don't disable firewall. You only open ports you need. Just see my answer.  `sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=8080/tcp --permanent`

Comment: I don't suggest you disable firewall, you had better open port that you need on firewall.